# What do these characters mean? I bought this vase at an antique shop

Tags: translation

[image]

Bought this item at an antique shop

Answer (score 0):

[伊萬里](https://tabiiro.travel/article/21050201/) ([Imari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imari,_Saga)) is the name of a Japanese city famous for porcelain

> Imari (伊万里市, Imari-shi) is a city located in Saga Prefecture on the island of Kyushu, Japan. Imari is most notable because of Imari porcelain, which is the European collectors' name for Japanese porcelain wares made in the town of Arita, Saga Prefecture. The porcelain was exported from the port of Imari specifically for the European export trade. As of October 1, 2016, the city has an estimated population of 54,907 and a population density of 220 persons per km2. The total area is 254.99 km2.

*里 in Japanese means 'village', I believe that is what it means here; 伊萬里 = 伊萬 Village*

*Coincidently, 萬里 in Chinese means "Thousands of miles"*

*伊萬里 Mandarin pinyin: Yīwànlǐ*